# How do I get a more fully-featured editor on my jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

Can anyone tell me what is this input type and how can i get it on my jsp. I don't know how to search for this on google.

[image]

don't rate me negative i don't know what to write on google to search this term.

Comment: have you tried inspect element?

Comment: This is a WYSIWYG editor. Search for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a third party Javascript WYSIWYG editor. Have a look at [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) as an example.

Comment: no, i didn't tried anything. as i told you i didn't know what to write as the search criteria.

Comment: are there any other examples with lesser functionality?

Comment: Now you know what they are, have a google for other examples and find one you like. If you can't find any with less functionality by default, read the TinyMCE documentation, you can customize the functionality displayed.